# How do I get the values of the checkbox on PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

To work on my PHP skills, I am currently create a simple form that will submit its values.

I have an option on my form with the checkbox where one can either check the option 'english' or 'french'.

However, I have problems on where to start and I dont know where to go.

Here is my code:

```
<tr>English<input type="checkbox" name='langue' value='anglais'/>French<input type="checkbox" name='langue' value='francais'/></td><tr>
<tr><td>Country:</td></tr>
   <select id='pays'>
   <option value='france'>France</option>
   <option value='angleterre'>England</option>
   </select></td></tr>
<tr><td>avis</td><td><input type='textarea' id='avis' cols='25' rows='15'>
</textarea></td></tr>
```

What do I do from here ?

All answers are appreciated

Comment: Do you actually have any PHP code?  Have you read any tutorials/guides on PHP?  Processing forms is one of the more basic skills that you will learn from any introduction to the language.

Comment: @Patrick Q oops, i was wrong, I just changed it

Comment: get like `$_POST['langue'];` in `php`

Answer (score 0):

I checked that you have not passed name in select so add name too..
For get value of checkbox you can simply get value by following code.

```
<?php 
// If you have form post method 
$_POST['pays'];
// If you have form get method 
$_GET['pays'];
```